# Почему последние символы secrets.token_urlsafe не совсем "случайные"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Был написан код, который миллион раз генерирует токен с разным количеством "рандомных" байт.

```py
from secrets import token_urlsafe
from collections import Counter


def count(n, b):
    counter = Counter()
    for i in range(n+1):
        counter[token_urlsafe(b)[-1]]+=1
    return counter


print("8 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 8)))
print("16 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 16)))
print("32 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 32)))
print("64 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 64)))
print("128 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 128)))
print("256 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 256)))
print("512 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 512)))
print("1024 bytes:", dict(count(1000000, 1024)))
```

Вывод **Python 3.7.3 64 bit** на **Windows 10**:

```
8 bytes: {'A': 62605, 'g': 62515, 's': 62276, 'E': 61883, 'o': 62509, 'w': 62818, '8': 62323, 'Y': 63026, '4': 62748, 'Q': 62739, 'k': 62258, 'U': 62889, 'I': 62214, 'c': 62741, '0': 62176, 'M': 62281}
16 bytes: {'w': 249345, 'g': 250300, 'A': 249395, 'Q': 250961}
32 bytes: {'U': 62447, '0': 62597, 'Q': 62606, 'Y': 62345, 'o': 62753, 'w': 62474, 'E': 62571, 'A': 62750, 'c': 62481, 'M': 62246, 's': 62733, 'I': 62182, '4': 62216, 'k': 62733, '8': 62499, 'g': 62368}
64 bytes: {'Q': 250227, 'A': 249719, 'w': 250005, 'g': 250050}
128 bytes: {'0': 62887, 'M': 62805, 'Q': 62504, 'w': 62499, 'A': 62274, 'I': 62755, 'Y': 62443, 'g': 62281, '8': 62385, 'U': 62674, '4': 62146, 'k': 62257, 'E': 62670, 's': 62594, 'o': 62405, 'c': 62422}
256 bytes: {'g': 249946, 'w': 250014, 'Q': 250291, 'A': 249750}
512 bytes: {'U': 61997, 'M': 62434, '8': 62406, 'Y': 62523, 'c': 62267, 'A': 62636, 'o': 62435, 'w': 62392, '4': 62569, 'k': 62724, 'g': 62287, 's': 62756, '0': 62660, 'E': 62647, 'I': 62593, 'Q': 62675}
1024 bytes: {'g': 249583, 'A': 250100, 'Q': 250405, 'w': 249913}
```

Видно, что количество уникальных символов при 8, 32, 128 и 512 байт всегда 16, причем символы одни и те же.

При 16, 64, 256 и 1024 всего 4, также повторяющихся.

Это какая-то особенность генерации?

Comment: А вы почитайте как работает base64. Подсказка: на последний символ в 16-байтном токене будет приходится 2 бита, т.е. как раз 4 разных значения

Comment: А случайность лучше проверять на token_bytes